# Regular Expression works different

Tags: php, regex

Regular Expression problem

I have Regular Expression code handling graphic files.

```
$view[content] = preg_replace("/(\<img )([^\>]*)(\>)/i", "\\1 name='target_resize_image[]' onclick='image_window(this)' style='cursor:pointer;' \\2 \\3", $view[content]);
```

At web pages, if there is not 'style" on html code, this code works fine. But if there is "style", the "style" code was changed into "style='cursor:pointer;".

I wnat, if there is "style='...'" at img, the style='...'" is added. If not, the "style" code should be "style='cursor:pointer;'".

The "preg_replace" gets rid of "style='aaaaaa'" at img code. That should be "style='cursor:pointer'".

code input

```
<img style="border-bottom: medium none; border-left: medium none; width: 160px; float: left; height: 160px; border-top: medium none; margin-right: 1em; border-right: medium none" alt="120131_12e1c8be2d6954ec9a3579ae57a64bfe_3EsTQWri2Zx9.gif" src="/data/cheditor4/1201/120131_02133169e006e1d08fc72fa5ff1e7a25_5KKOd8zrZhluXoqpiN.gif" />
```

code output

```
<img style="cursor:pointer" alt="120131_12e1c8be2d6954ec9a3579ae57a64bfe_3EsTQWri2Zx9.gif" src="/data/cheditor4/1201/120131_02133169e006e1d08fc72fa5ff1e7a25_5KKOd8zrZhluXoqpiN.gif" />
```

code - should be

```
<img style="cursor:pointer;border-bottom: medium none; border-left: medium none; width: 160px; float: left; height: 160px; border-top: medium none; margin-right: 1em; border-right: medium none" alt="120131_12e1c8be2d6954ec9a3579ae57a64bfe_3EsTQWri2Zx9.gif" src="/data/cheditor4/1201/120131_02133169e006e1d08fc72fa5ff1e7a25_5KKOd8zrZhluXoqpiN.gif" />
```

Any helpful comment would be appreciated.

Comment: You're aware of stylesheets, right? `img { cursor: pointer; }` ... problem solved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your regexp creates this output:

```
<img name='target_resize_image[]' onclick='image_window(this)' style='cursor:pointer;' style="border-bottom: medium none; border-left: medium none; width: 160px; float: left; height: 160px; border-top: medium none; margin-right: 1em; border-right: medium none" alt="120131_12e1c8be2d6954ec9a3579ae57a64bfe_3EsTQWri2Zx9.gif" src="/data/cheditor4/1201/120131_02133169e006e1d08fc72fa5ff1e7a25_5KKOd8zrZhluXoqpiN.gif" / >
```

Please note, that you have -of course- two style attributes in this string. Apparently you use some kind of HTML validation, which automatically "fixes" this by removing the 2nd one and just leaves you with `style='cursor:pointer;'`.

You *could* improve your regexp. Using a pattern like `/(alt|style|src)=("[^"]*")/i` with `preg_match_all` will allow you to extract the attributes of your `img` tag, then manipulate them and build a new HTML string from it.

Anyway, **I do not recommend manipulating HTML using RegExp’s** at all. It is much more simple and robust to Use DOM tools. Have a look at the [Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/). This simple code

```
require 'simple_html_dom.php'; // http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/
$html = str_get_html($img); // load HTML as DOM object
$img = $html->find('img', 0); // find your tag
$img->style = "cursor:pointer;".$img->style; // manipulate the style attr
$img->name="target_resize_image[]"; // set other attr's
$img->onclick="image_window(this)";
echo htmlspecialchars($html); // output HTML as string
```

gives you the output

```
<img style="cursor:pointer;border-bottom: medium none; border-left: medium none; width: 160px; float: left; height: 160px; border-top: medium none; margin-right: 1em; border-right: medium none" alt="120131_12e1c8be2d6954ec9a3579ae57a64bfe_3EsTQWri2Zx9.gif" src="/data/cheditor4/1201/120131_02133169e006e1d08fc72fa5ff1e7a25_5KKOd8zrZhluXoqpiN.gif" name="target_resize_image[]" onclick="image_window(this)" />
```

Voila! And it doesn’t depend on the order of your attributes, on used quotes, spaces and line-breaks.

**EDIT: WindStory has requested a non-DOM Solution**

The solution depends very much on the given strcuture of your input string. If you, for example, know for sure, that every given `img` already has a `style` attribute, you can do it with a plain replace:

```
$img = str_replace('style="', 'style="cursor:pointer; ', $img); // add info to the given style-attr
$img = str_replace('<img', '<img new_attribute="value" ', $img); // add new attrs
```

Having less guarantees on your given tag, you can use the RegExp I mentioned above to extract the attributes from the img tag

```
// extract attr's, depends on double quotes
$Attrs = array();
if (preg_match_all('/(alt|style|src)="([^"]*)"/i', $img, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER)) {
    foreach ($matches as $match) {
        $Attrs[$match[1]] = $match[2];
    }
}

// change/add attr's
$Attrs['style'] = empty($Attrs['style']) ? 'cursor:pointer' : 'cursor:pointer; '.$Attrs['style'];
$Attrs['name'] = 'target_resize_image[]';
$Attrs['onclick'] = 'image_window(this)';

// build new HTML
$new_img = '<img ';
foreach ($Attrs as $key => $value) $new_img .= $key.'="'.$value.'" ';
$new_img .= '/>';
```

See it in action [here](http://codepad.viper-7.com/bv2Mhx).

Hope that helps.

**EDIT 2: WindStory has asked for a more fault-tolerant RegExp solution**

Here is a small function, to add/change attributes in a given HTML string. It supports single or double quotes for attribtues, but no missing quotes and it will not work, if a single quote is enclosed by double quotes and vice versa.

```
function add_attr($html, $name, $value, $append = null) {
    $attr_pattern = "/\b({$name}=['\"])([^'\"]*)(['\"])/i";
    if (preg_match($attr_pattern, $html, $regs)) {
        if (!is_null($append)) {
            $value = $regs[2].$append.$value;
        }
        $replace = "\\1$value\\3";
        $html = preg_replace($attr_pattern, $replace, $html);
    } else {
        $tag_pattern = '/<[\w]+\b/i';
        $replace = "\\0 $name=\"$value\"";
        $html = preg_replace($tag_pattern, $replace, $html);
    }
    return $html;
}
```

Insert a html-Tag as `$html`, define the `$name` of the attribute and define the `$value`. If the attribute is already present, the value will be replaced, otherwise it will be added. If you set `$append`, the `$value` will be appended and `$append` will be used as concatenation sign.

This

```
$img = add_attr($img, 'style', 'cursor:pointer', '; ');
$img = add_attr($img, 'name', 'target_resize_image[]');
$img = add_attr($img, 'onclick', 'image_window(this)');
echo htmlspecialchars($img);
```

will outout

```
<img onclick="image_window(this)" name="target_resize_image[]" style="border-bottom: medium none; border-left: medium none; width: 160px; float: left; height: 160px; border-top: medium none; margin-right: 1em; border-right: medium none; cursor:pointer;" alt="120131_12e1c8be2d6954ec9a3579ae57a64bfe_3EsTQWri2Zx9.gif" src="/data/cheditor4/1201/120131_02133169e006e1d08fc72fa5ff1e7a25_5KKOd8zrZhluXoqpiN.gif" />
```

Comment: DerVO/ Thanks a lot for your kind and detailed reply. I would like to have other way than dom parser, that's why this code works for querying records. If possible, please let me know more simple regular expression.

Comment: I appreciate for your valuable reply. However I would like to ask additional question.
I want to satify style=" and style=' simultaniously, so please let me have another tip for this code.

 `$img = str_replace('style="', 'style="cursor:pointer; ', $img); // add info to the given style-attr`
 
According to your instruction, "style="" works fine, however there are "style='".

Awaiting for your further reply.

Comment: DerVO/ I appreciate for your kind answer.

Comment: You may express your appreciation through accepting his solution by clicking the checkmark ;)